# django-registration custom backend

Tags: django, authentication, registration, django-registration

I have successfully implemented my auth/login custom backend, and now i am trying to implement my own django-registration custom backend.
The django-registration code seems to work fine, if i use the normal authentication from  contrib.auth . If not (in my case i want to use my own newly created custom authentication) i get an

> User object has no attribute backend

.

my registration backend:

```
from django.conf import settings
#from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login

from registration import signals
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
class MyRegistrationBackend(object):

    def register(self, request, **kwargs):
        """
        Create and immediately log in a new user.

        """
        print "debug"
        username, email, password = kwargs['username'], kwargs['email'], kwargs['password1']
        User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)

        # authenticate() always has to be called before login(), and
        # will return the user we just created.

        auth = MyAuthBackend()

        new_user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                     user=new_user,
                                     request=request)
        return new_user
```

then my auth backend:

```
class MyAuthBackend(object):
    """
    Authenticates against django.contrib.auth.models.User. with my modifications
    """
    supports_inactive_user = True

    """
    This function does not upgrade the user password hasher
    """
    def check_password(self,password, encoded):
        if not password or not is_password_usable(encoded):
            return False

        password = smart_str(password)
        encoded = smart_str(encoded)

        if encoded[0] == "$":
            encoded = encoded[1:]   #make it compatible so that drupal 7 sha512 hasher can work properly

        if len(encoded) == 32 and '$' not in encoded:
            hasher = get_hasher('unsalted_md5')
        else:
            algorithm = encoded.split('$', 1)[0]          
            hasher = get_hasher(algorithm)

        is_correct = hasher.verify(password, encoded)

        return is_correct

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            if self.check_password(password, user.password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Any ideas?? I believe that maybe i am instantiating the `auth = MyAuthBackend()` the wrong way.. or maybe its something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting as described in the docs on [specifying authentication backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#specifying-authentication-backends)

Then, in your register method, use the `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` method to log in (see [how to log a user in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#how-to-log-a-user-in)) instead of instantiating an instance of your backend manually. That authenticate method should take care of setting the user `backend` attribute, so you shouldn't get any errors.